# Trouble with SQL SELECT inside switch_to_blog()

Tags: multisite, switch-to-blog, get-row

I'm using switch_to_blog() and restore_current_blog() to perform some functions across a multi site install. One of the things I'm trying to do is select a very specific post using get_row(). My function looks like this:

```
$prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
$tbl = $prefix;
$product = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM {$tbl}_posts WHERE ID = 4253");
print_r($product); exit;
```

The post with ID 4253 definitely exists, and I know for sure that the prefix is correct, however print_r returns absolutely nothing, nor does `echo $product->post_title;`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** You have an extra underscore in your table name, it becomes `wp__posts` in your case. Better use like how I have shown below :)

---

First, use table names like the following and try var_dump to see if it returns NULL. In case the Post ID doesn't exist, `$product` will be `NULL`, which only var_dump can show.

`$product = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = 4253");
var_dump( $product );`

Comment: For unknown reasons, using $wpdb->posts won't work here, but you were right about the extra underscore.